# Show MessageBox from thread as it were from the main thread in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, messagebox

There is a thread which can throw an exception, and when does so it is caught, a certain message box is shown, and then the software closes.

However, the problem is that since it is not the program's main thread, when I show the message box, the program window remains free for the user to interact with. It does not lock the screen, unlike when the message box is shown above the main window. I want to avoid this.

I wanted to know what would be the best way to do this. Up to now, I thought of using some kind of thread communication (never used this in C#) to raise the message box from the main thread.

Raising the thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyClass.MyMethod));
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

The capture of the exception is in various parts of `MyMethod`. It is a thread that keeps running nonstop in a loop since the start of the program. The cause of the exception would be a network error.

Comment: How are you managing the thread (e.g. `Thread`, `BackgroundWorker`)? Where might the exception get raised? Post code snippets to describe how it works today.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud it is Thread, I added further explanation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can probably just invoke it on the `Dispatcher`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show(...));
```

Comment: This is a WPF app, not a winform app.

Comment: Or use BeginInvoke() for async operation.

Comment: I used the following: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Error")));` right now to test, unfortunately, it didn't "locked" the screen. EDIT: Now it worked, I just messed something while debugging. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there may be a sort of reentrancy hazard here: if it is possible for such an exception to occur while the `MessageBox` is being shown (and it might be, as a nested message loop will be created), then you could end up displaying multiple message boxes.  I have seen this happen in applications before, and the result is not pretty: in some cases, an endless stream of new `MessageBox` dialogs can be created.  Be careful.  (Note: this is not directed at this particular answer, but at the problem in general.)

Comment: `Application.Current` doesn't seem to exist in .NET 3.5 - is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SynchronizationContext` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)